# Change infinite scroll loading image

Tags: javascript, php, html, infinite-scroll

I have been trying to use [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll) with Masonry on Wordpress and I can't change the loader.gif.

I'm getting a 404 error in firebug.

I am using register script for the template path in functions.php

```
wp_register_script( 'image-folder', 'myscript_url' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'image-folder' );
$translation_array = array( 'templateUrl' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
```

This is what I have in my js file:

```
var templateUrl = object_name.templateUrl;
loading: {
    finishedMsg: $('<div class="finmsg">No More Posts.</div>'),
    msgText: 'Loading More Posts',
    img: " url'"+templateUrl+"/images/loader.gif' "
},
```

I have the correct path, but the problem is it keeps adding the image path onto the website url for the current page i.e.

http://mysite.co.uk/news-events/http:/mysite.co.uk/im/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/loader.gif"

Answer (score 0):

First, your `loadingImg` path should be dynamic using `get_template_directory_uri();` ([here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)). When using a file from a theme, ressources path should never be "hard-written".

Then what is the error message (if it exists) ?

Comment: Thanks. There is no error message. What happens is the default loader.gif appears, but my own loader.gif doesn't. loadingImg is mean to override the default according to the docs, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Ok. I've finally found out that **img** is what relates to the loader.gif. Now I have a 404 error. Yes, the path is wrong.

Comment: Nice ! Don't forget to mark the question as solved !

Comment: Oh this isn't solved. The path makes no sense to me. It just appends gobledygook onto the page url. mysite/news-events/url'%3C?=%20get_bloginfo(%22template_url%22);%20?%3E/images/loader.gif%27"